# How to soft proof an image in LightRoom with CMYK ICC profiles?

Tags: printing, icc-profile, soft-proofing, cmyk

I want to print an image from a printing service ([Saal Digital](https://www.saal-digital.at/)) that provides ICC profiles for their different printers, but these ICC profiles are in the CMYK colorspace. Lightroom had the capability to soft proof with CMYK ICC profiles, and I am able to use RGB ICC profiles, but the newest version of Lightroom Classic CC will not let me use the CMYK ICC profiles.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem, or do I have to do the soft-proofing and adaptions in Photoshop? Is it possible to reformat these ICC profiles to the RGB color space, but still correctly soft proof CMYK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [blurb: Soft proofing and ICC Profiles in Lightroom](https://support.blurb.com/hc/en-us/articles/207792256-Soft-proofing-and-ICC-Profiles-in-Lightroom), **Lightroom does not support CMYK,** and **you need to hop over to Photoshop or InDesign to softproof CMYK**. Apparently, use of CMYK ICC profiles was removed from Lightroom because [they did not work reliably](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2318223).